# a faster way to compute the error of a vector

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab

For a given vector $(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ I am trying to compute

[image]

I wrote the following code

```
for l = 1:n
  for k = 1:n
    error = error + norm(x(i)-x(j))
  end
end
```

This code is not fast, especially when $n$ is large. I am aware that I am double counting actually... But how may I avoid it? How can I speed up my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there inner loop  as shown in code in your mathematical notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which is fast:

```
d = (abs(bsxfun(@minus, x, x.')));
result = sum(d(:));
```

---

Or alternatively use [`pdist`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) with `'cityblock'` distance (which for one-dimensional observations reduces to absolute difference). This computes each distance once, so you need to multiply the sum by `2`:

```
result = 2*sum(pdist(x(:),'cityblock'));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple speed up?

```
for a=1:n
  for b=a+1:n
     error = error + 2*norm(x(a)-x(b))
  end
end
```

For a scalar, `norm` just gives `abs`.
So,

```
error = sum(abs( bsxfun(@minus, error,error') ))
```

will do the same thing.

also check out `pdist` which will do this for vectors, using vector norms, in an even faster way.